# Align text using FLEX

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, sass, flexbox

Trying to achieve the text "Cena" beneath "John" where the star icon will be floating right centered.

Not Working.

```
<div className='d-flex justify-content-between'>John
<p>Cena</p>
<span>StarIcon</span>
 </div>
```

Comment: is this `</>` supposed to be valid syntax? => not sure if that would help anyway `</p>`

Comment: Yes its valid in React. Its called Fragments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing two things:

- `align-items-center` class on the parent. You should read [Bootstrap's documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/utilities/flex/#align-items)
- "John" and "Cena" should be in a container.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class='d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center'>
  <span>
    John<br/> Cena
  </span>
  <span>StarIcon</span>
</div>
```